# How to edit user form which had dropdown in codeIgniter?

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter

I have users in the admin module. Against each user row I have edit user option. when admin clicks on that edit user option. He will see edit user form with fields. Out of those form fields one of the filed is drop down which is user profile type.

Now from the database I will get an array of all the details about that user which admin editing called `$user_details`. But from the database what I will get is user profile id in the field name like this `$user_details['profile_id'];`

At the same time I had another array which maps profile id's with profile names. That is called as `$profile`

Now when admin clicks on edit first he needs to see the profile_name of that user before editing. And when he clicks on that drop down he needs to see what are the profile types available to changes.

I am not able to get idea how to do this.

Bu this is what I have tried

```
<label>Profile: <?php echo form_error('profile'); ?></label> <br />
       <select class="styled" name="profile_id">
           <?php foreach($profiles as $profile) { ?>
               <option value="<?php echo $profile['profile_id']?>" <?php if ( set_value('profile_id') == $user_details['profile_id']) {?>selected="selected"<? } ?>><?php echo $profile['profile_name']?></option>
           <?php } ?>
      </select>
```

Comment: You have a php opening tag in `selected="selected"<? } ?>>` without the php indicator, not a massive problem unless your server is not set up to recognize short tags.

Comment: yeah that's not a problem

Comment: How to show previous user profile as a default profile type and all the available profile types in the drop down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy if you are going to use Codeigniter's builtin form_dropdown

```
$options    =   array();
foreach($profiles as $profile){
    $options[$profile['id']]    =   $profile['profile_name'];
}
$select =   isset($user_details['profile_id']) ? $user_details['profile_id'] : 0;

form_dropdown('profile_id',$options , $select , 'class= "styled" ');
```

It takes 4 parameters. 3rd and 4th are optional. 3rd is the key you want to be selected and 4th is used for other attributes like class , id etc. The first one is name and 2nd one is array.

For details see the [Form Dropdown](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html) User guide.